# tablelayoutpanel space between iitems when form get resize

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

normal size

[image]

when form get resize
there will be space between them
And it keeps getting bigger! depends on how big this form is..
i already set table to autosize and set percent to 100% but nothing happens

[image]

Comment: Seeing the columns and row properties of the TableLayoutPanel would help.  Is the Button set to Dock.Fill?

Comment: @LarsTech yes all item in layout set to dock fill

Comment: Add a new TLP. Adjust the last two Rows in the designer to ± the desired size. Add a Button in the last Row and anchor it Left/Bottom/Right. Set it's Row to AutoSize. Add the TextBox, anchor it Left/Top/Right, set its Row to AutoSize (the two Bottom Rowws should adjust to the Controls height). Add whatever you have in the top Row. Set its Row to Percent = 100%. After that, Dock->Fill that Control. Anchor or Dock the TLP to complete the setup.

Comment: Is that TextBox set for multi-line?  If not, it won't dock fill.

Comment: When the setup is complete, you can also Dock the Button and TextBox, if you want. I suggest to keep the anchors.

Comment: thank you everyone, now my problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this method solved my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in comment, set the Rows of Button and TextBox to AutoSize, don't use a fixed (absolute) size there. The TLP can adjust anyway, but changes in the Screen DPI or *resolution* can mess things up.

Comment: @Jimi ok sir, now i set button and textbox to autosize and datagridview to 100%

Comment: All right. Make some tests, to see if it glitches out in some configurations. Please, don't *sir* me, we're colleagues :)

Comment: ok hehe I tested and everything works fine. thank you @Jimi